# Есть подозрение, что мой почтовый сервер рассылает спам

Tags: email, сервер

На почтовый ящик стали приходить письма такого содержания, хотя я ничего не отправлял. Такое ощущение, что с моего сервера кто-то рассылает спам. Захожу в админку почтового сервера, там зареган только мой почтовый ящик. А отправитель в письмах указан такого типа Kozin@example.ru Как так получается? Или это просто развод какой-то? И как защититься в случае, если это опасно?

```
This message was created automatically by mail delivery software.A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of itsrecipients. This is a permanent error. The following address(es) failed:  somebody@mailbox.ru    Unrouteable address------ This is a copy of the message, including all the headers. ------Return-path: <Kozin@example.ru>Received: from [XX.XXX.XXX.XXX] (helo=XX.XXX.XXX.XXX)        by s5.pdg.pl with esmtpa (Exim 4.80.1)        (envelope-from <Kozin@example.ru>)        id 1Wz6DJ-0003Gr-MF        for rogalev@zelnet.ru; Mon, 23 Jun 2014 17:31:21 +0200Message-ID: <6399E06C17C3ED4E9297DE62767BEECD@XX.XXX.XXX.XXX>From: =?windows-1251?B?xOjt4A==?= <Kozin@example.ru>To: <rogalev@zelnet.ru>Subject: =?windows-1251?B?zeDh5el05SDq7vjl62VrIOTl7fzjYezoLiDD?=        =?windows-1251?B?5GUg6PUg4uf/8vwgliD36HRh6fLlIO3o5mUu?=Date: Mon, 23 Jun 2014 19:29:25 +0400MIME-Version: 1.0Content-Type: multipart/alternative;        boundary="----=_NextPart_000_1B93_01CF8F19.718241B0"X-Priority: 3X-MSMail-Priority: NormalX-Mailer: Microsoft Outlook Express 6.00.2900.5931X-MimeOLE: Produced By Microsoft MimeOLE V6.00.2900.6157This is a multi-part message in MIME format.------=_NextPart_000_1B93_01CF8F19.718241B0Content-Type: text/plain;        charset="windows-1251"Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable=C7=E0p=E0=E1=EE=F2a=F2=FC =E2 =E8=ED=F2=E5p=ED=E5=F2e =EDa =E1=E8=EDa=F0==ED=FBx o=EF=F6=E8o=ED=E0x c =EFo=EC=EE=F9=FC=FE =F1=E5p=F2=E8=F4=E8=F6=E8==F0=EE=E2a=ED=ED=FB=F5 =E1p=EE=EAepo=E2 =D0=EEcc=E8=E8...[uriyhhdl]=20[tiwugkq]=203a=F0=E5=E3=E8c=F2=F0=E8p=F3=E9=F2ec=FC =ED=E0 =F1=E0=E9=F2=E5 =E8 =F3=E7==ED=E0=E9=F2e =EF=EE=E4=F0o=E1=ED=EE=F1=F2=E8 - =FD=F2=EE =E1ec=EF=EB=E0=F2==EDo![gfwwqc][kcqbqyoi]=20[qnugnqvc]=20[ujib]=20------=_NextPart_000_1B93_01CF8F19.718241B0Content-Type: text/html;        charset="windows-1251"Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN"><HTML><HEAD><META content=3D"text/html; charset=3Dwindows-1251" http-equiv=3DContent-=Type><META name=3DGENERATOR content=3D"MSHTML 8.00.6001.23588"></HEAD><BODY><FONT style=3D"FONT-FAMILY: Verdana; FONT-SIZE: 9pt" size=3D2></FON=T><DIV><FONT style=3D"FONT-FAMILY: Verdana; FONT-SIZE: 9pt"=20size=3D2><B>=C7=E0p=E0=E1=EE=F2a=F2=FC=20=E2=20=E8=ED=F2=E5p=ED=E5=F2e=20=EDa=20=E1=E8=EDa=F0=ED=FBx=20o=EF=F6=E8o=ED=E0x=20c =EFo=EC=EE=F9=FC=FE=20=F1=E5p=F2=E8=F4=E8=F6=E8=F0=EE=E2a=ED=ED=FB=F5=20=E1p=EE=EAepo=E2=20=D0=EEcc=E8=E8...</B><FONT=20color=3Dwhite>[uriyhhdl]</FONT> <BR><FONT=20color=3Dwhite>[tiwugkq]</FONT>=20<DIV><A=20href=3D"http://www.webcreativas.com/bp">3a=F0=E5=E3=E8c=F2=F0=E8p=F3=E9=F2=ec=FC=20=ED=E0 =F1=E0=E9=F2=E5=20=E8 =F3=E7=ED=E0=E9=F2e=20=EF=EE=E4=F0o=E1=ED=EE=F1=F2=E8=20- =FD=F2=EE=20=E1ec=EF=EB=E0=F2=EDo!</A><FONT=20color=3Dwhite>[gfwwqc]</FONT></DIV><BR><BR><FONT=20color=3Dwhite>[kcqbqyoi]</FONT> <BR><FONT=20color=3Dwhite>[qnugnqvc]</FONT> <BR><FONT=20color=3Dwhite>[ujib]</FONT> </FONT></DIV></BODY></HTML>------=_NextPart_000_1B93_01CF8F19.718241B0--
```

Comment: конкретные ip-адреса и имена доменов лучше замазать как-нибудь в тексте вопроса

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ничего страшного. Кто-то использует ваш e-mail адрес `kozin-at-[...]dmy.ru` (доменное имя привожу не полностью, поскольку эти конкретные идентифицирующие подробности не имеют отношения к сути вопроса) в качестве адреса отправителя для рассылки спама, поэтому все уведомления о недоставке возвращаются на этот адрес.

Обратите внимание, что нигде в заголовках нет ни ip-адреса, ни имени вашего почтового сервера. Письмо отправляется с указанного в заголовке хоста 87.245.XX.XX. Он, очевидно, не имеет никакого отношения к вашему домену.

По своему почтовому серверу всегда проверяйте журналы самого почтового сервера.